# Only return fields that contain numbers or special characters EXCEPT . Error

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

In Redshift I want to return fields that contain numbers or special characters **EXCEPT .** (anything other and a-z and A-Z)

The following gets me anything that contains a number but I need to extend this to any special character except full stop (.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM  table
WHERE name ~ '[0-9]'
```

I need something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM  table
WHERE name ~ '[0-9]' OR name ~'[,#';:@~[]{}etcetc'
```

Sample Data:

```
name
john
joh1n1
j!ohn!
jo!h2n
joh.n
jo.&hn
j.3ohn
j.$9ohn
```

Expected Output:

```
name
joh1n1
j!ohn!
jo!h2n
jo.&hn
j.3ohn
j.$9ohn
```

Comment: `WHERE name ~ '[^[:alnum:].]'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That returns the opposite of what I want.

Comment: Then `WHERE name !~ '[^[:alnum:].]'`

Comment: Please check [my updated solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58556959/3832970), it looks to work for the samples you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
WHERE name !~ '^[[:alpha:].]+$'
```

Here, all records that do not consist of only alphabetic or dot symbols will be returned. `^` matches the start of a string position, `[[:alpha:].]+` matches one or more letters or dots and `$` matches the end of string position.

If it is for PostgreSQL you may use

```
WHERE name SIMILAR TO '%[^[:alpha:].]%'
```

The `SIMILAR TO` operator accepts POSIX character classes and bracket expressions and wildcards, too, and requires a full string match. So, `%` allows any chars before any 1 char other than letter or dot (`[^[:alpha:].]`), and then there may also be any other chars till the end of the string.

Comment: I think the OP just wants:  `WHERE name ~ '[^[:alnum:].]'`.

Comment: @Matt I fixed it, now, both solutions work, see [online demo](https://rextester.com/UMK31341).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name  FROM  table WHERE name !~* '[a-z]'
```

This means: match on `name`s that do not contain any alphanumeric character.

[Operator `!~*`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html) means:

> Does not match regular expression, case insensitive

---

**Edit** based on the provided sample data and expected results.

If you want to match on names that contain at least one character other than an alphabetic character or a dot, then you can do:

```
select * from mytable where name ~* '[^a-z.]'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1bf9ea37157869d1e05463b1eb938d8e)**:

```
with mytable(name) as (values
    ('john'), 
    ('joh1n1'), 
    ('j!ohn!'), 
    ('jo!h2n'), 
    ('joh.n'),
    ('jo.&hn'),
    ('j.3ohn'),
    ('j.$9ohn')
)
select * from mytable where name ~* '[^a-z.]'
```

```
| name    |
| :------ |
| joh1n1  |
| j!ohn!  |
| jo!h2n  |
| jo.&hn  |
| j.3ohn  |
| j.$9ohn |
```

Comment: Thats not what I am asking, let me add more to question

Comment: @Matt: I updated my answer with a solution that seemingly works for your sample data/ expected results.

Comment: This is bringing back results with only a . in them